# How to find out the ID of a lookup list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I have a Employee list that contains 2 lookup fields (dept and manager).
How do I get the ID for the manager lookup field?

```
                    FieldLookupValue mgrItem = new FieldLookupValue();                       
                    mgrItem.LookupId = Convert.ToInt32(department); //giving department throws an error like "input string was not in correct format"
                    item["Manager"] = mgrItem;
```

So what should be the ID that I should provide?

Kindly help! Thanks :)

Comment: are you sure that department is returning a valid string that can be converted to int? e.g you should have it "5"

Comment: Well when I tried out with "1", it changes to the first item present in the list. @NderonHyseni

Comment: it seems that department is not a string that can be converted to int

Answer (score 3):

try this one with department.

```
department = department.split('#')[1];
mgrItem.LookupId = Convert.ToInt32(department);
item["Manager"] = mgrItem;
```

Comment: Using this gives an error like "Index was outside the bounds of the array. " @NderonHyseni